# CrossplatformInput Joystick is not working in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit

[image]I have connected a joystick from the standard assets library from the unity store, but the input is not being read. The car can be controlled by the arrow keys,but the joystick is not working.

here is my code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;

public class rearwheeldrive : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float maxAngle = 30;
    public float maxTorque = 300;
    public WheelCollider[] wheelArray;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float angle = maxAngle * CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float torque = maxTorque * CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Vertical");
        wheelArray[0].steerAngle = angle;
        wheelArray[1].steerAngle = angle;

        wheelArray[2].motorTorque = torque;
        wheelArray[3].motorTorque = torque;

        foreach (WheelCollider wheelcollider in wheelArray)
        {
            Vector3 P;
            Quaternion Q;
            wheelcollider.GetWorldPose(out P, out Q);
            Transform wheelshape = wheelcollider.transform.GetChild(0);
            wheelshape.position = P;
            wheelshape.rotation = Q;

        }

    }
}
```

Even after changing maxAngle * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"); to maxAngle * CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal"); it takes the arrow key input whilst the joystick is not working.

Code Of Joystick object

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

namespace UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput
{
    public class Joystick : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler, IDragHandler
    {
        public enum AxisOption
        {
            // Options for which axes to use
            Both, // Use both
            OnlyHorizontal, // Only horizontal
            OnlyVertical // Only vertical
        }

        public int MovementRange = 100;
        public AxisOption axesToUse = AxisOption.Both; // The options for the axes that the still will use
        public string horizontalAxisName = "Horizontal"; // The name given to the horizontal axis for the cross platform input
        public string verticalAxisName = "Vertical"; // The name given to the vertical axis for the cross platform input

        Vector3 m_StartPos;
        bool m_UseX; // Toggle for using the x axis
        bool m_UseY; // Toggle for using the Y axis
        CrossPlatformInputManager.VirtualAxis m_HorizontalVirtualAxis; // Reference to the joystick in the cross platform input
        CrossPlatformInputManager.VirtualAxis m_VerticalVirtualAxis; // Reference to the joystick in the cross platform input

        void OnEnable()
        {
            CreateVirtualAxes();
        }

        void Start()
        {
            m_StartPos = transform.position;
        }

        void UpdateVirtualAxes(Vector3 value)
        {
            var delta = m_StartPos - value;
            delta.y = -delta.y;
            delta /= MovementRange;
            if (m_UseX)
            {
                m_HorizontalVirtualAxis.Update(-delta.x);
            }

            if (m_UseY)
            {
                m_VerticalVirtualAxis.Update(delta.y);
            }
        }

        void CreateVirtualAxes()
        {
            // set axes to use
            m_UseX = (axesToUse == AxisOption.Both || axesToUse == AxisOption.OnlyHorizontal);
            m_UseY = (axesToUse == AxisOption.Both || axesToUse == AxisOption.OnlyVertical);

            // create new axes based on axes to use
            if (m_UseX)
            {
                m_HorizontalVirtualAxis = new CrossPlatformInputManager.VirtualAxis(horizontalAxisName);
                CrossPlatformInputManager.RegisterVirtualAxis(m_HorizontalVirtualAxis);
            }
            if (m_UseY)
            {
                m_VerticalVirtualAxis = new CrossPlatformInputManager.VirtualAxis(verticalAxisName);
                CrossPlatformInputManager.RegisterVirtualAxis(m_VerticalVirtualAxis);
            }
        }


        public void OnDrag(PointerEventData data)
        {
            Vector3 newPos = Vector3.zero;

            if (m_UseX)
            {
                int delta = (int)(data.position.x - m_StartPos.x);
                delta = Mathf.Clamp(delta, - MovementRange, MovementRange);
                newPos.x = delta;
            }

            if (m_UseY)
            {
                int delta = (int)(data.position.y - m_StartPos.y);
                delta = Mathf.Clamp(delta, -MovementRange, MovementRange);
                newPos.y = delta;
            }
            transform.position = new Vector3(m_StartPos.x + newPos.x, m_StartPos.y + newPos.y, m_StartPos.z + newPos.z);
            UpdateVirtualAxes(transform.position);
        }


        public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData data)
        {
            transform.position = m_StartPos;
            UpdateVirtualAxes(m_StartPos);
        }


        public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData data) { }

        void OnDisable()
        {
            // remove the joysticks from the cross platform input
            if (m_UseX)
            {
                m_HorizontalVirtualAxis.Remove();
            }
            if (m_UseY)
            {
                m_VerticalVirtualAxis.Remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it Like :

```
  public Joystick mJoystick; 

  float angle = maxAngle * mJoystick.Horizontal;
  float torque = maxTorque * mJoystick.Vertical;
```

EDIT : I have used the same asset, works fine using the below settings.

[image][image]

```
using System.Collections; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using UnityEngine; 
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;



public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour 
{

    // Use this for initialization  
   void Start () 
   {

   }        

    // Update is called once per frame  
   void Update ()
   {

        float angle =  CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float torque =  CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Vertical");


        print("Angle : " + angle + "  ,  Torque : " + torque);

    } 

}
```

Comment: 'Joystick' does not contain a definition for 'Horizontal' and no accessible extension method 'Horizontal' accepting a first argument of type 'Joystick' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Replace 'Joystick' with the script attached on the joystick object in hierarchy.

Comment: The name of the script attached is "Joystick"

Comment: Edit your question and attach 1- screen shot of inspector while selecting the joystick object. 2- "Joystick Script"

Comment: I have edited answer. Please have a look. Your first approach should work. Try some debugging to see if the joystick works in an empty scene like i did.